# ERROR TypeError: spanEl.getBoundingClientRect is not a function

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, serve

```
ERROR TypeError: spanEl.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
    at _guessBsVersion (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:163317:25)
    at isBs3 (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:163343:26)
    at CarouselComponent.get isBs4 [as isBs4] (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:112171:90)
    at Object.updateDirectives (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:132386:438)
    at Object.updateDirectives (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:89094:39)
    at checkAndUpdateView (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:88585:14)
    at callViewAction (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:88951:21)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:88908:17)
    at checkAndUpdateView (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:88586:5)
    at callViewAction (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:88951:21)
ERROR TypeError: spanEl.getBoundingClientRect is not a function
    at _guessBsVersion (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:163317:25)
    at isBs3 (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:163343:26)
    at CarouselComponent.get isBs4 [as isBs4] (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:112171:90)
    at Object.updateDirectives (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:132386:438)
    at Object.updateDirectives (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:89094:39)
    at checkAndUpdateView (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:88585:14)
    at callViewAction (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:88951:21)
    at execEmbeddedViewsAction (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:88908:17)
    at checkAndUpdateView (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:88586:5)
    at callViewAction (C:\Users\sagar h\Desktop\MYRIDZ\falcon-mobikes-website\dist\server\main.js:88951:21)
```

I got this error while running npm run serve:ssr , after npm run build:ssr. After adding domino to server.ts file am getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this in your `server.ts` after instantiating `domino`

```
(global as any).HTMLElement = window.HTMLElement;
(global as any).HTMLElement.prototype.getBoundingClientRect = () => {
  return {right: '', left: '', top: '', bottom: ''};
};
```

**Edit**
You should instantiate `domino` like this

```
const domino = require('domino');
const win = domino.createWindow('/path/to/browser/index.html');
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;
global['navigator'] = win.navigator;
```

Comment: TS2339: Property 'HTMLElement' does not exist on type 'Window'. am getting this error while building project after adding the above code snippet

Comment: How did you instantiate domino?

Comment: @David, worked for me, just you missed a curly bracket